# Using Highcharts with FastAPI

Tags: plot, highcharts, python-3.7, fastapi

I started with FastAPI and am new to Highcharts. My goal is to create a simple plot of Highcharts using FastAPI instead of Flask.

in my `app.py` I have,

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from os.path import join, realpath, dirname

app = FastAPI()
dir_path = dirname(realpath(__file__))
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory=join(dir_path, "static")), name="static")
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory=join(dir_path,  "templates"))


origins = [
"http://localhost:3000",
"localhost:3000"
]


app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)



@app.get("/graph")
def index(request, chartID='chart_ID', chart_type='line', chart_height = 500):
    chart = {"renderTo": chartID, "type": chart_type, "height": chart_height, }
    series = [{"name": 'Label1', "data": [1, 2, 3]}, {"name": 'Label2', "data": [4, 5, 6]}]
    title = {"text": 'My Title'}
    xAxis = {"categories": ['xAxis Data1', 'xAxis Data2', 'xAxis Data3']}
    yAxis = {"title": {"text": 'yAxis Label'}}
    render_dict = dict(request=request, chartID=chartID, chart=chart, series=series,
                   title=title, xAxis=xAxis, yAxis=yAxis)

    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", render_dict)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

In the `static` folder I have `main.js` and `main.css` scripts, and in the `templates` folder is my `index.html` file. But when I run it, I get `422 Unprocessable Entity` error.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(chartID).highcharts({
        chart: chart,
        title: title,
        xAxis: xAxis,
        yAxis: yAxis,
        series: series
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 100px;
}
header {
    background-color:rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
    color:#ffffff;
    display:block;
    font: 14px/1.3 Arial,sans-serif;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
}
header h2{
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}
header a, a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fcfcfc;
}

.actions, .chart {
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 34px;
}
button {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E3E3E3;
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #F6F6F6 inset;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 8px 0 9px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    width: 150px;
}
button:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D9D9D9;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #EAEAEA inset;
    color: #222222;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:active {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D0D0D0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #E3E3E3 inset;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
</head>

<body class = "body">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


    <body>
        <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
        {% for p in paragraph %}
        <p>{{ p }}</p>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if pageType == 'about' %}
        <p>Contact box thing is here</p>
        {% else %}
        <p>not about page</p>
        {% endif %}

        <div id={{ chartID|safe }} class="chart" style="height: 100px; width: 500px"></div>
        <script>
            var chart_id = {{ chartID|safe }}
            var series = {{ series|safe }}
            var title = {{ title|safe }}
            var xAxis = {{ xAxis|safe }}
            var yAxis = {{ yAxis|safe }}
            var chart = {{ chart|safe }}
        </script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
            <script src="../static/main.js"></script>

    </body>


</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `422 Unprocessable Entity` is due to incorrect data format provided to the endpoint.

You should define the type of the `request` object in your endpoint as such

```
from fastapi import Request

# more code

@app.get("/graph")
def index(request: Request, chartID='chart_ID', chart_type='line', chart_height = 500):
```

This way, `fastapi` will know that the first variable will not be provided by the user (i.e. who `GET`s the request), but instead it will be filled by `fastapi`.